# Flutter / Dart package integration_test with null safety

Tags: flutter, dart

As I understand it, the [Package integration_test](https://pub.dev/packages/integration_test) package is not null type safe. Can the package be used for the current Flutter version (version> 2.0)? If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: this package can be used in flutter 2.2.1 , its migrated to null safety there. I upgraded my flutter to latest, my tests are running fine in that. Though I am not sure about 2.2.0

Answer (score 9):

as montionned in Readme file, the package is ****DEPRECATED**

This package has been moved to the Flutter SDK. Starting with Flutter 2.0.

it should be included as:

```
dev_dependencies:
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
```