# The method 'watchPerformance' isn't defined for the type 'IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding'

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm currently doing the integrated_test codelab on https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-app-testing/#6.

I'm on step 6 where I have to test the performance of the test_app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import 'package:testing_app_codelab/main.dart';
import 'package:testing_app_codelab/testing_app.dart';


void main() {
  group('Testing App Performance Tests', () {
    final binding = IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()
        as IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding;
          

    binding.framePolicy = LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBindingFramePolicy.fullyLive;
    
    testWidgets('Scrolling test', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(TestingApp());
      
      final listFinder = find.byType(ListView);
      await binding.watchPerformance(() async { // error is here
      await tester.fling(listFinder, Offset(0, -500), 10000);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      await tester.fling(listFinder, Offset(0, 500), 10000);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      }, reportKey: 'scrolling_summary');
    });
  });
}
```

I've gone through the IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding documentation and watchPerformance() is a method of it(please check: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-integration_test_integration_test/IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding/watchPerformance.html).

The error I get on VS code is:

**The method 'watchPerformance' isn't defined for the type 'IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'watchPerformance'.**

When I run the Integration test on my Android phone I get this error:

**Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'watchPerformance'.
await binding.watchPerformance(() async {**

Answer (score 1):

I got the idea to solve this problem from this post [Flutter / Dart package integration_test with null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67621517/flutter-dart-package-integration-test-with-null-safety)

The problem was that integration_test dependency doesn't support null-safety.

when you check which dependencies have null safety support using this command:

```
dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
```

The output is:

```
Showing dependencies that are currently not opted in to null-safety.
[✗] indicates versions without null safety support.
[✓] indicates versions opting in to null safety.

Package Name      Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest    

direct dependencies:
integration_test  ✗0.8.1   ✗0.8.1      ✗0.8.1      ✗1.0.2+3  

dev_dependencies: all support null safety.
You are already using the newest resolvable versions listed in the 'Resolvable' column.
Newer versions, listed in 'Latest', may not be mutually compatible.
```

This means that it's legacy and doesn't have support.

To solve this I changed the `pubspec.yaml` from this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.1
  test: ^1.19.5
  integration_test: ^0.8.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Changed to this instead:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.1
  test: ^1.19.5

dev_dependencies:
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

After this, I ran `flutter pub get` on the terminal and the error disappeared.

Now when I hover over the `watchPerformance()` method I get this info:

```
Future<void> watchPerformance(Future<void> Function() action, {String reportKey = 'performance'})
package:integration_test/integration_test.dart

Watches the [FrameTiming] during action and report it to the binding with key reportKey.

This can be used to implement performance tests previously using [traceAction] and [TimelineSummary] from [flutter_driver]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a general programming error that will occur. I will put an answer in because the error description for these is often rubbish at telling you what is going on here.

The error is telling you the function called `watchPerformance` on the object `IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding` (a var here called `binding`), does not exist.

Does the function use a captial W instead of lower case? Take another look at the docs and check everything is spelled correctly etc.

Comment: Its a method of the binding class so the method name convention is smallBig(I apologize if I've pointed out the obvious). The method of IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding is watchPerformance().

Comment: Np @Mbuso I don't bother with flutter so I won't know the conventions. Irregardless from my perspective the error is saying that the function doesn't exist (camel-case or not), so there may be a missing extension package or inclusion.

This being said is it supposed to take in a another set of functions? If so then there may be a cascading error coming from one of those containered functions giving us an incorrect message when it bubbles out.

Have you tried reducing the inner commands on the function either to nothing or simple commands and seeing if that works?

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help, I've found the solution. dart has become a null-safety language meaning that dependencies that are legacy need to add support for it. integration_test dependencies don't support null-safety and that was causing issues with IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding. Because of this, the compiler couldn't find the method watchPerformance(). Thank you so much for assisting me as your reply made me wake up and look for a solution which is below.

Comment: Np, good catch! I guess it failed to define the funcs in the dependency because they couldn't implement the null-safety and rather than tell u, it just failed.

Maybe put in your own answer to this and mark it as the answer in case anyone else gets the same issue.